# Two angular projects with different versions of Angular how can I combine them?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have two projects in Angular. One is in Angular CLI 1.7.2 and the other is a different version of Angular that is older. The older version contains all of the HTML/CSS and some JavaScript files. The structure of both projects is completely different, the older version doesn't have app.component file etc. Is there a way to make the older version work with the newer version? Like combine the two projects?

I need them to have the same structure, and dependencies etc. The newer version has `HttpClient` code that I don't think would work on the older version. Any advice?

Comment: U have wrong tag. `angular` tag = Angular 2+ ang `angularjs` = Angular version<2 so Angular 1.7.2 is `angularjs`. Angular 2+ is in TypeScript and Angular.js is in JavaScript.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to just start re-writing the older project to the newer version manually, or build them separately and run them in their own "sandbox".